# Split an Arraylist

Tags: c#, dynamic-columns

Background information: I'm iterating through a site collection, which stores all the sites I'm looking for in the correct hierarchical order. When I try to display this information in a nested format, in addition to multiple columns on the same row format is where I run into the problem.

I have a for loop that adds items to an ArrayList. I have another for loop that iterates through the "example" ArrayList. I need to break or split this ArrayList each time "-----" occurs. Problem is ArrayList does not support .Split(), so I'm out of ideas. My overall goal is to display the information in the ArrayList in nested dynamic-columns that are based on the number of "-----".

```
ArrayList example = new ArrayList();
example.Add("Door");
example.Add("A1"); //nested
example.Add("A2"); //nested
example.Add("-----");
example.Add("House");
example.Add("A1"); //nested
example.Add("A2"); //nested
example.Add("-----");
example.Add("Fence");
example.Add("A1"); //nested
example.Add("A2"); //nested
example.Add("-----");
```

When I iterate through the list a table is built and displayed like the example below:

```
|Door| A1 | A2 | House | A1 | A2 | Fence | A1 | A2|
```

However, I need the data in the table to be displayed like this example below:

```
|Door| House | Fence| <----This is the desired output that I'm trying to achieve.
|A1  | A1    | A1   | <----This is the desired output that I'm trying to achieve.
|A2  | A2    | A2   | <----This is the desired output that I'm trying to achieve.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `ArrayList`?

Comment: What version of C# are you using? `ArrayList` is a dated library. If you're working in C# 3 or above you should use the generic `List<T>` instead.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal You mean C# 2.0 or above.

Comment: I think you need to provide context on how this is going to be used, why a table needs to be stored in a linear array, is this schoolwork type of problem with very strict requirements or are you flexible on types and algorithms that can be used.

Comment: I'm not limited to a specific datatype. Now that I think about it I believe I opted for ArrayList because the order did not matter. However, now that a specific order is a requirement it blew a whole into the ArrayList.

Comment: I've added additional information. I'm limited to VS2008, .NET FW 3.5 SP1

Comment: Then you should be using `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: Also, you really need to be a lot clearer about what's going on. What do you mean, "it displays like"? Displays how? What code are you using to "display"? What do you mean, "nested"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I moved some items around in an attempt to clarify what I am getting versus what I would like to achieve. Please let me know if this does not clear up things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
class Thing {
    public string name;
    public string a;     // This may also be a List<string> for dynamic Add/Remove
    public string b;
    // ...

    public Thing(string Name, string A, string B) {
        name = Name; a = A; b = B;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Thing> things = new List<Thing>();
things.Add(new Thing("Fence", "A1", "A2"));
things.Add(new Thing("Door", "A1", "A2"));
// ...
```

I always use a class to store a bunch of information that belongs together. The best example for this are the derivations of `EventArgs`, like the `PaintEventArgs`. All needed information comes with one instance.
This enables you also to implement more features. For example, I amost always override the `ToString()` method of that class, so I am able to display the objects contents while debugging or simply adding the objects to a `ListBox` or a `ComboBox`, because they call `ToString()` to display.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not make more sense to make a Data Structure that works with the type of data you're looking to store? I don't know if this is a specific restriction of the project or if it's homework, but it seems like using the ArrayList to store Objects that have the needed datamembers would be easier when it comes time to print it out.

Comment: Sometimes that's not entirely possible.

Comment: I understand, but in this case, there doesn't seem to be any specific reason as to why this isn't possible. Especially since this is C#.

Comment: BTW, I agree that getting rid of the ArrayList to begin with is the better way.  Now that I've reread his question, he does state that he puts it in that format... Which begs the question: why?

Answer (score 1):

This would be better solved using a `List` of `List`s or something similar.
For example:

```
List<List<string>> example = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> door = new List<string>();
door.Add("Door");
door.Add("A1");
door.Add("A2");
example.Add(door);
...so on and so forth...
```

Then looping through it is just a matter of the following:

```
foreach (List<string> list in example)
{
  foreach (string s in list)
  {
     //magic
  }
}
```

Comment: It's possible his project is in an older version C#/.NET that doesn't have `List<T>`

Comment: How do you know to add string `"Door"` to list `door`?

Comment: `I4V`, does the name of the list really matter? It was for an example, it could have been called `foo` for all it matters. The point was that an `ArrayList` isn't the best datastructure choice for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Split`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Split.cs) method from [moreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library, but because `ArrayList` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` you'll have to call `Cast<T>()` first.

```
var result = source.Cast<string>().Split("-----");
```

But first of all, I would suggest using `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList` at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your `ArrayList` into a list of lists as follows:

```
var list = new List<List<string>>();
var current = new List<string>();
list.Add(current);

foreach (string element in example)
{
    if (element.Equals("-----"))
    {
        current = new List<string>();
        list.Add(current);
    }
    else
    {
        current.Add(element);
    }
}

if (!current.Any())
{
    list.Remove(current);
}
```

But, as others have said, it's probably best to avoid `ArrayList` completely if you can.